# Java: How to control JPanel aspect ratio?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, aspect-ratio

I have a JPanel which I want to remain a square however I want it to size so that it fills the maximum amount of space possible in its parent JFrame but remains square i.e. it takes the shortest side of the JFrame as the square width.

I've searched the net, checked all layout managers and none seem to have a simple solution to this very simple problem.

Comment: event from ComponentListener delayed by Swing Timer,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a `GridBagLayout` and `ComponentListener`,

For example: (inspired from: https://community.oracle.com/thread/1265752?start=0&tstart=0)

```
public class AspectRatio {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final JPanel innerPanel = new JPanel();
        innerPanel.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);

        final JPanel container = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        container.add(innerPanel);
        container.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
                resizePreview(innerPanel, container);
            }
        });
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("AspectRatio");
        frame.getContentPane().add(container);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(600, 600);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static void resizePreview(JPanel innerPanel, JPanel container) {
        int w = container.getWidth();
        int h = container.getHeight();
        int size =  Math.min(w, h);
        innerPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(size, size));
        container.revalidate();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this works perfectly. The only modification I made is replaced the layout manager of the container JPanel with FlowLayout instead of GridBagLayout to reduce the flickering as FlowLayout bases the size of its components solely on their preferred size which is what you want as the preferred size is set manually after each resize.

Answer (score 11):

[image]
[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class YouAreSoSquare {

    private static JPanel createPanel() {
        // GBL is important for the next step..
        JPanel gui = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        JPanel squareComponent = new JPanel() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                // Relies on being the only component
                // in a layout that will center it without
                // expanding it to fill all the space.
                Dimension d = this.getParent().getSize();
                int newSize = d.width > d.height ? d.height : d.width;
                newSize = newSize == 0 ? 100 : newSize;
                return new Dimension(newSize, newSize);
            }
        };
        squareComponent.setBackground(Color.RED);
        gui.add(squareComponent);
        return gui;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception useDefault) {
                }
                JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("..So Square");
                mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                mainFrame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
                mainFrame.add(createPanel());
                mainFrame.pack();
                mainFrame.setMinimumSize(mainFrame.getSize());
                mainFrame.setVisible(true);
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's my take for a most reusable solution, which use the Swing Layout concept. So that you can use it simply by copy/pasting this Layout class and set the layout on your Swing Containers.
I was surprised not to find it already done on the net, so here it is ! A main method is included, it creates a JFrame similar to the screenshots by 
Andrew Thompson

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.LayoutManager;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

//@Slf4j
/**
 * A Swing Layout that will shrink or enlarge keep the content of a container while keeping
 * it's aspect ratio. The caveat is that only a single component is supported or an exception
 * will be thrown.
 * This is the component's {@link Component#getPreferredSize()} method that must return the
 * correct ratio. The preferredSize will not be preserved but the ratio will.
 * 
 * @author @francoismarot
 * @see https://gist.github.com/fmarot/f04346d0e989baef1f56ffd83bbf764d
 */
public class SingleComponentAspectRatioKeeperLayout implements LayoutManager {

    /** Will be used for calculus in case no real component is in the parent */
    private static Component fakeComponent = new JPanel();

    public SingleComponentAspectRatioKeeperLayout() {
        fakeComponent.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(0, 0));
    }

    @Override
    public void addLayoutComponent(String arg0, Component arg1) {
    }

    @Override
    public void layoutContainer(Container parent) {
        Component component = getSingleComponent(parent);
        Insets insets = parent.getInsets();
        int maxWidth = parent.getWidth() - (insets.left + insets.right);
        int maxHeight = parent.getHeight() - (insets.top + insets.bottom);

        Dimension prefferedSize = component.getPreferredSize();
        Dimension targetDim = getScaledDimension(prefferedSize, new Dimension(maxWidth, maxHeight));

        double targetWidth = targetDim.getWidth();
        double targetHeight = targetDim.getHeight();

        double hgap = (maxWidth - targetWidth) / 2;
        double vgap = (maxHeight - targetHeight) / 2;

        // Set the single component's size and position.
        component.setBounds((int) hgap, (int) vgap, (int) targetWidth, (int) targetHeight);
    }

    private Component getSingleComponent(Container parent) {
        int parentComponentCount = parent.getComponentCount();
        if (parentComponentCount > 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(this.getClass().getSimpleName()
                    + " can not handle more than one component");
        }
        Component comp = (parentComponentCount == 1) ? parent.getComponent(0) : fakeComponent;
        return comp;
    }

    private Dimension getScaledDimension(Dimension imageSize, Dimension boundary) {
        double widthRatio = boundary.getWidth() / imageSize.getWidth();
        double heightRatio = boundary.getHeight() / imageSize.getHeight();
        double ratio = Math.min(widthRatio, heightRatio);
        return new Dimension((int) (imageSize.width * ratio), (int) (imageSize.height * ratio));
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension minimumLayoutSize(Container parent) {
        return preferredLayoutSize(parent);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension preferredLayoutSize(Container parent) {
        return getSingleComponent(parent).getPreferredSize();
    }

    @Override
    public void removeLayoutComponent(Component parent) {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(); // the panel we want to keep it's aspect ratio
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 600));
        panel.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);

        JPanel wrapperPanel = new JPanel(new SingleComponentAspectRatioKeeperLayout());
        wrapperPanel.add(panel);

        frame.getContentPane().add(wrapperPanel);
        frame.setSize(450, 450);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```